# How to put a javascript code to onclick event Odoo 8.0

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, odoo

I already searched a lot of posts, here and in the odoo forum, but i didn't get any example that works. What i want to do is very simple in fact. I need to put a javascript code to a button onclick event, in the button that already exists. All my attempts have failed. I think that my js code runs before right time, because it's always runs, so the HTML element still doesn't exists and nothing is added to element when it is loaded.

One of a many ways that i have tried bellow:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    var _t = openerp._t;
    var _lt = openerp._lt;
    var QWeb = openerp.qweb;
    var oepetstore = openerp.oepetstore = {};

    oepetstore.Test = openerp.Widget.extend({
        events: {            
            // events binding example            
            "click .button_test": "myFunctionHandler",        
        },                

        myFunctionHandler: function(){            
            alert('ok from button!');
        },                

        start: function() {            
            alert('ok!'); //this code always runs        
        }    
    });

    var pet = new oepetstore.Test();
    pet.appendTo(openerp.web.$el);

    return oepetstore;
})();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In odoo website or backend part?

Comment: In a frontend of odoo module.